# Liquibase, create foreign keys in Oracle, preconditions

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, liquibase

I have a production and a QA instance of my application into which I'm integrating Liquibase. This means DDL and data already exists (or not if on development box). I have to create a changeLog which records everything as RAN on the non-empty DBs but execute actually on empty DBs.
I'm on a good way but I'm a bit stuck with creating the foreign keys. (the database is Oracle).

(In general I'm creating preconditions which expects various objects to NOT exists and on fail MARK_RAN the change).

I find difficulties writing a correct precondition when I don't know the exact name of foreign keys, which may or may not exist.
There is `<foreignKeyConstraintExists>` tag in liquibase (precondition) but it takes only `schemaName` and `foreignKeyName` attributes (and they are required). I don't know the foreign key names for sure in these instances as they are out of my control.

You can write custom SQL in preconditions like:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="bob">
    <preConditions onFail="WARN">
        <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from oldtable</sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <dropTable tableName="oldtable"/>
</changeSet>
```

So I only have to create a custom SQL query which can check if a column on table `A` has foreign key referencing table `B` and use the result as a precondition.
This is where my problem is because you can do it in Oracle but it's quite bloat:

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                        AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
  WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R' AND a.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
  AND a.column_name = 'MY_COLUMN'
  AND c_pk.table_name = 'MY_OTHER_TABLE';
```

This prints a row if a foreign key exists on `MY_COLUMN` of `MY_TABLE` which references to `MY_OTHER_TABLE`. After rewriting it to COUNT you can check if there's foreign key without knowing it's name.

**My question:**
I have dozens of foreign keys, do I really have to write this big SQL such dozens of times? Any suggestions, like outsourcing this to some function? Thanks!

Would it worth asking Liquibase developers to make `<foreignKeyConstraintExists>` 's name attribute optional and introduce the referenced table attribute alogn with local column name?

Comment: It is a good idea, I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1639

Comment: Really looking forward to see it in Liquibase!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more possibility: implementing the interface http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/precondition/CustomPrecondition.html and use it as a custom precondition. More info: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html

Here is the implementation (verified):

```
import liquibase.database.Database;
import liquibase.exception.CustomPreconditionErrorException;
import liquibase.exception.CustomPreconditionFailedException;
import liquibase.precondition.CustomPrecondition;
import liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory;
import liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey;
import liquibase.structure.core.Schema;
import liquibase.structure.core.Table;
import liquibase.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * {@link CustomPrecondition} implementation that checks if a column on a table
 * has a foreign key constraint for some other table.
 */
public final class CheckForeignKey implements CustomPrecondition {

    /**
     * Schema.
     */
    private String schemaName;

    /**
     * Table name (that has the column).
     */
    private String tableName;

    /**
     * Column (that might have the foreign key).
     */
    private String columnName;

    /**
     * Referenced table of the foreign key.
     */
    private String foreignTableName;

    @Override
    public void check(final Database db)
            throws CustomPreconditionFailedException,
            CustomPreconditionErrorException {

        try {
            // The fkey we are looking for
            final ForeignKey fKey = new ForeignKey();

            // Schema, base table
            fKey.setForeignKeyTable(new Table());
            if (StringUtils.trimToNull(getTableName()) != null) {
                fKey.getForeignKeyTable().setName(getTableName());
            }

            final Schema schema = new Schema();
            schema.setName(getSchemaName());
            fKey.getForeignKeyTable().setSchema(schema);

            // Base column
            fKey.addForeignKeyColumn(getColumnName());

            // Referenced table
            fKey.setPrimaryKeyTable(new Table());
            if (StringUtils.trimToNull(getForeignTableName()) != null) {
                fKey.getPrimaryKeyTable().setName(getForeignTableName());
            }

            if (!SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getInstance().has(fKey, db)) {
                throw new CustomPreconditionFailedException(
                        String.format(
                                "Error fkey not found schema %s table %s column %s ftable %s",
                                getSchemaName(), getTableName(),
                                getColumnName(), getForeignTableName()));
            }
        } catch (final CustomPreconditionFailedException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new CustomPreconditionErrorException("Error", e);
        }
    }

    public String getSchemaName() {
        return schemaName;
    }

    public void setSchemaName(final String schemaName) {
        this.schemaName = schemaName;
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public void setTableName(final String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }

    public void setColumnName(final String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public String getForeignTableName() {
        return foreignTableName;
    }

    public void setForeignTableName(final String foreignTableName) {
        this.foreignTableName = foreignTableName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to do it like you suggested if you dont know foreign key constraint names.

But if you can modify database then you could prepare sql script which prepare another sql script which renames all FK to well known names. Something like that:

```
BEGIN

FOR cur IN (
    SELECT 
      c_list.CONSTRAINT_NAME as FK_NAME,
      'FK_' || c_dest.TABLE_NAME || '_' || substr(c_dest.COLUMN_NAME, 1, 20) as NEW_FK_NAME,
      c_src.TABLE_NAME as SRC_TABLE,
      c_src.COLUMN_NAME as SRC_COLUMN,
      c_dest.TABLE_NAME as DEST_TABLE,
      c_dest.COLUMN_NAME as DEST_COLUMN
    FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS c_list, ALL_CONS_COLUMNS c_src, ALL_CONS_COLUMNS c_dest
    WHERE c_list.CONSTRAINT_NAME = c_src.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND c_list.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = c_dest.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND c_list.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
    AND c_src.TABLE_NAME IN ('<your-tables-here>')
    GROUP BY c_list.CONSTRAINT_NAME, c_src.TABLE_NAME, c_src.COLUMN_NAME, c_dest.TABLE_NAME, c_dest.COLUMN_NAME;
) LOOP

    -- Generate here SQL commands (by string concatenation) something like:
    -- alter table SRC_TABLE rename constraint FK_NAME to NEW_FK_NAME;
    -- then paste this sql commands to some other script and run it

END LOOP;

END;
```

This is one time migration.

After this migration you know whats your FK constraint names are and you can use <foreignKeyConstraintExists> precondition in your changesets.

Comment: Thanks, could be a good solution in general. Sadly, I don't have access to QA and production databases as they are handled by assigned DBAs.